# Char table casting to short with pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new in C++ development while learning I came across the following procedure:

```
char A[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
std::cout << *((short*)A+2) << std::endl;

output:
1541
```

Can someone explain why the output is like this? Is it some kind of casting A[2] to short pointer?

Comment: Try `std::cout << (A[5] << 8) + A[4] << std::endl;` and see if the output makes sense.

Comment: As a beginner, don't do that. As an experienced developer, don't do that.

Comment: It's one of job interview questions in Motorola Solutions that i found on the internet.

Comment: This is exactly why C++ has static_cast<new type> to have compiler to shout at you what a crazy person you are. It is interesting exercise though. Convert A to pointer to short and then move it by two which is in original twice that. And then return what values under 4 and 5 combined will represent as short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What it does:**

`A` decays to a `char*` to the first element of the array. That pointer is converted to a `short*`. Pointer arithmetic is performed, moving it the space of two shorts, and then it is dereferenced. The memory it points to, when interpreted as a `short`, reads as 1541 (`00000101 00000110`).

**Why not to do it:**

1. It is undefined behavior. Strict aliasing forbids casting pointers of one type to another arbitrary type and accessing the object. There are cases that are legal, but this isn't one of them.<sup>See note.</sup>
2. There is no guarantee that `sizeof(short) == 2`. If `sizeof(short) == 4`, that line would read past the end of the array.
3. The value you get depends on endianness.
4. Technically the `short` value could end up being a trap representation, but in practice I highly doubt any integral trap values exist anywhere.

---

Note: There are a surprising number of upvoted/accepted answers on Stack Overflow that contain lines similar to `*(short*)A`, but it still violates strict aliasing.

Comment: Thanks finally a substantive answer not like "don't do that and go away".